# Can functions/symbols in the same assembly file be re-ordered to different virtual addresses when linked?

Tags: assembly, memory, linker, elf

I have some code written in assembly which I need to copy at runtime (code that copies is written in C), hence I need to get the size of the function. I've written the function this way in assembly:

```
.globl function_foo
function_foo:
        ...
        ...
.globl function_foo_end
function_foo_end:
```

```
extern void function_foo(void);
extern void function_foo_end(void);

memcpy(dest, function_foo, (uintptr_t)function_foo_end - (uintptr_t)function_foo);
```

The code works as expected, but I'm concerned that if the symbols are re-ordered by the linking process, say if `function_foo_end` is moved before `function_foo`, or if `function_foo` and `function_foo_end` are not contiguous in memory, then `memcpy` may copy the wrong size.

Are these symbols guaranteed to be in order and contiguously placed in memory?

Comment: FYI, "ISO C++ forbids using pointer to a function in subtraction.".  Also, the compilers that I tried do the subtraction at runtime, so that's good in case linker relaxation changed something size-wise.  Though, to your question, I don't think there's any way for the linker to move around/reorder content of a section of one object file.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Do linker relaxations ever change size?  I thought they usually filled space with a NOP, or by making an instruction longer on ISAs where if that's possible, so the distance between two symbols on opposite sides of the relocation stay the same distance apart.  And yes, other than processing relocations, the linker doesn't know the difference between code and data, so can't do anything that would break a data array even if it's in `.text`.  (Unless `.type foo, @function` has way more effect than I think it does.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, on RISC V linker relaxation shrinks/shortens the code, mostly function call sequences,  As a result, the linker has to fix up local/internal branches (and potentially other stuff), and of course, the compiler/assembler has to emit relocations for those local/internal branches, too.  (I don't know to what length the compiler goes to elide relocations when pc-relative branches don't cross a function call, probably not much, since it doesn't buy anything at runtime, but also wouldn't be too hard..)  The compiler has to ask for relaxation using a particular relocation type for calls.

Comment: In RISC V assembly, you can ask for relaxation using the "call" pseudo instruction, which makes doing that different from writing `auipc`; `jal` yourself — no way I know to request relaxation for those individual instructions; relaxation is built into pseudo instruction expansion, which is a bit out there if you ask me as I also don't know how to turn it off for "call".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linker works at granularity of sections so as long as your labels are within the same `.text` block linker will not split them apart.

There are certain post-link optimization tools (like [BOLT](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/bolt)) which can do more aggressive transformations of binary code, including moving labels around.

One alternative may be to compile your program two times:

- first test build is just to extract the function size (via `readelf` or like)
- you can then pass the extracted size to second compilation via macro (`-DFUNC_SIZE=...`)

Comment: The above `.S` file is assembled to a `.o` file, which is combined with many other `.o` files, and hence the `.text` section contains many other labels. Can the linker shuffle the `.text` section as a whole and hence move these two labels apart from each other? Or did you mean that since these two labels are in the same `.o` file, they're in the same block and this block will not get split up?

Comment: @ackerleytng "since these two labels are in the same .o file, they're in the same block and this block will not get split up" - those blocks are called "sections" in linker jargon and there can be several of them within the same .o file. As long as your labels are withing the same section (sections are marked with `.text`, `.data`, `.rodata`, etc. directives in assembly) the linker will not split them up.